# How to add multiple TextView dynamically to the define LinearLayout in main.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I know it's possible to add some layouts like `Button` and `TextView` to a `LinearLayout`.  I want to create more then one `TextView` based on the condition of a for loop.

I have tried it with my own way, but I am not able to create it.  Does anybody know how to create it?

The for loop will be different based on the condition.  Please help me regarding this.  Is it possible to create the array of `TextView`?

I already have set the layout with

```
setContentView(R.layout.result_page);
```

I am using Function to add that view to my existing view:

**The function is:**

```
public void addAll()
{
     LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);     
     layout.setOrientation(1);       
     TextView name[] = null;     
     TextView website[] = null;     
     TextView category[] = null;        
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
     {         
         name[i] = new TextView(this);         
         name[i].setText("Name = Shreyash");         
         website[i] = new TextView(this);         
         website[i].setText("Website = shreyah.co.cc");         
         category[i] = new TextView(this);         
         category[i].setText("Website Category = OWN");         
         layout.addView(name[i]);         
         layout.addView(website[i]);         
         layout.addView(category[i]);     
    } 
}
```

But after that if I run the Application, it shows me error like:

```
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.quiz.spellingquiz/com.quiz.spellingquiz.ResultDisplayPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at com.quiz.spellingquiz.ResultDisplayPage.addAll(ResultDisplayPage.java:59)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at com.quiz.spellingquiz.ResultDisplayPage.onCreate(ResultDisplayPage.java:34)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-08 11:03:28.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(318):     ... 11 more
```

Where am I wrong regarding this?

I got the result with DeeV's code like this:
[image]

But I want to set the Word under the tag word, and Answer under the tag answer. But how it is possible?
I think I have to set another LinearLayout for that. How I set another LinearLayout for that type of appearance?

Comment: Please add some example code to show what you have already tried.  This will help us see what isn't working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need to create an array if you need to change the `TextViews` later.  However, if you do need to make an array, then something like this should work.

```
List<TextView> textList = new ArrayList<TextView>(NUM_OF_TEXTS);
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_TEXTS; i++)
{
   TextView newTV = new TextView(context);
   newTV.setText("New message.");
   newTV.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
   /**** Any other text view setup code ****/
   myLinearLayout.addView(newTV);
   textList.add(newTV);
}
```

If the text is static once created, then you can simply remove any reference to the list in code, and it will still be added to the `LinearLayout`.

**EDIT:**

Assuming I understand your question right, you want the layout to be something like this:

```
Word:
Big
Answer:
42

Word:
Small
Answer:
Tough

Word:
Example
Answer:
Another Answer
```

In that case, you literally don't have to do much.  `LinearLayout` will put everything in the order that you place it with `addView`.  To update my previous code, this should work:

```
List<TextView> wordList = new ArrayList<TextView>(NUM_OF_WORDS);
List<TextView> answerList = new ArrayList<TextView>(NUM_OF_ANSWERS);

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_WORDS; i++){
   TextView blankText = new TextView(context);
   TextView wordText = new TextView(context);
   TextView answerText = new TextView(context);
   blankText.setText(" ");
   wordText.setText("Word:");
   answerText.setText("Answer:");

   TextView newWord = new TextView(context);
   newWord.setText(**** some method of getting the word ****);
   TextView newAnswer = new TextView(context);
   newAnswer.setText(**** some method of getting the answer ****);
   /**** Any other text view setup code ****/

   myLinearLayout.addView(wordText);
   myLinearLayout.addView(newWord);
   myLinearLayout.addView(answerText);
   myLinearLayout.addView(newAnswer);
   myLinearLayout.addView(blankText);

   wordList.add(newWord);
   answerList.add(newAnswer);
}
```

Comment: Ok Your code is works. but i want all textview in to Vertical Orientation. And the Background of the Whole layout is transperant so i can able to show myMainLayout design or background. then how should it be possible ?

Comment: Hello DeeV, I have implement your code. it works but i want some changes to do. Please see my edited Question. And guide me regarding it. Thanks.

Comment: Think of LinearLayout as a stack.  You want a vertical orientation, so all you have to do is add the TextViews in order to get the vertical stack.  That's pretty much the beauty of LinearLayout in that it's so simple.  I'll edit in an example that I think will work.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Do u Know how to set the Gravity from thi way ? As i am not able to set the Grvity of ImageView. I am able to set the Gravity of textView but not Image View.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of would involve LinearLayout.LayoutParams.  Add the gravity you want to the LayoutParams then pass it to the TextView via `setLayoutParams()`.  There are more complicated yet better ways, but I think that would be the simplest for this example.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: I can't get this code to work.
I tied obtaining the `myLinearLayout` instanced via `new(context)` and commenting `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_textViews);`
but when my layout renders is completley empty

Comment: You need to call `setContentView(mLinearLayout)` so that your Activity has a view to show.

Answer (score 2):

```
        LinearLayout lila = new LinearLayout(this);
        ArrayList<Button> alb = new ArrayList<Button>();
        int nButton = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < nButton; i++)
        {
            alb.add(new Button(this));
            lila.addView(alb.get(i));
        }
        //works the same way with TextView
        alb.get(5).setText("myButton");
```

Maybe this could help.

**EDIT : Sorry strictly the same as DeeV.**